# How to select a Top 1 from another Top-selection?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database I'm filtering my records using a Top 101. My goal is to get the last Id which is being returned in my filtered list.

Is there a way to get this in a single statement for use in my SQL Command?

```
SELECT TOP 101 Id FROM Messages WHERE Validation = 2 AND Shown > 0 ORDER BY Id DESC
```

And from this list I need the last entry.

How can I get this in a single query?

Thank you.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQL-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 temp.Id 
from (SELECT TOP 101 Messages.Id FROM Messages WHERE Validation = 2 AND Shown > 0 ORDER BY Messages.Id ASC) as temp
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your code returns at least 101 rows, then you can use [`OFFSET`/`FETCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx):

```
SELECT Id
FROM Messages
WHERE Validation = 2 AND Shown > 0
ORDER BY Id DESC
OFFSET 100
FETCH NEXT 1 ROW ONLY;
```

This ANSI-standard construct was introduced in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: best method for me